# Split a character string by the symbol "*"

Tags: r, string, split

```
> test = "23*45"
```

I'd like to split `test`by the symbol `*`

I tried...

```
> strsplit(test,'*')
```

and I got...

```
[[1]]
[1] "2" "3" "*" "4" "5"
```

What I aim to have is:

```
[[1]]
[1] "23" "45"
```

Comment: @silvaran: please stop adding `string` and `character` tags to questions.  They're too all-encompassing to be useful, and you're wasting the time of the reviewers (who should **not** be approving them).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the star...

```
test = "23*45"

strsplit( test , "\\*" )
#[[1]]
#[1] "23" "45"
```

The `split` is a regular expression and `*` means the preceeding item is matched zero or more times. You are splitting on nothing , i.e. splitting into individual characters, as noted in the **Details** section of `strsplit()`. `\\*` means *treat `*` as a literal `*`.

Alternatively use the `fixed` argument...

```
strsplit( test , "*" , fixed = TRUE )
#[[1]]
#[1] "23" "45"
```

Which gets R to treat the split pattern as literal and not a regular expression.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at this package:
http://www.rexamine.com/resources/stringi/

To install this package simply run:

```
install.packages("stringi")
```

Example:

```
stri_split_fixed(test, "*")
```

Comment: +1 Not sure why this was downvoted. This seems like a pretty interesting resource (though it seems like overkill for this question).

Comment: Yes, it is. It uses ICU lib and works fine with every encoding. Also properly deals with NA value.

Comment: I did not downvote, but the link does not work on my machine.  Perhaps that prompted someone else to downvote.

Comment: @MarkMiller even in your web browser? You can always download the file and run this in R manually.

Comment: If I copy the link and paste it into my web browser I get the message 'Oops! Google Chrome could not find www.rexamine.com'.  I have not tried running the source command in R.  I am simply suggesting that if someone else could not get the link to work they might have downvoted for that reason.

Comment: I have no idea why you cannot download this. If you want I can send you this via email or you could try to google rexamine.